# How set a object datasource to a subReport in reportviewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, reportviewer

I Configured my report to add show the respective values, in one point I decide to set a subreport into my principal report. Reading I found that i need to bind my subreport to a event to passing the datasource like this

```
 this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(MySubreportEventHandler);

void MySubreportEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e) 
    { 
        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ObjectDataSource3"));
    }
```

And I defined in my aspx the follow object datasource

```
asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource3" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="obtenerDetallesGestion" 
        TypeName="SodexoSAT.Reports.DataSets.CamposGestion">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="idGestion" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

The value of the first parameters was setting in the first report. Now my problem it's that the reportviewer say's the follow

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
The value cannot be null. Parameter name: value
```

What am I doing wrong??